# How to replace a portion of a SQL query dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am writing SQL queries using Node.js. After the query is formed I will call the database to get the data.

My query is something like below,

```
and technology in (values) and subTechnology in (values) and geo in (values) and
```

And so on. Now the `values` may be `('a')` or `('b', 'c', 'a')` in this way. It will come dynamically.

Now I want to delete the portion and `technology in (values)`. I can use `str.replace()` method. But, for the `values` portion then I have to hard code it. That I don't want. And `values` also comes dynamically.
Is there a shortcut approach to achieve this?

I don't want to use `for` loop or something like that.

Comment: Maybe use regex to match what you want from the actual string and get it?
Or maybe have a list of these `technology`, `subtechnology` and `geo` and use this list to generate the final query? You can delete the unwanted columns from the list before generating the query.

Comment: yes, it can be done using substr() and indexOf() method

Comment: What's the use case here? Why can't you just compose the query the way you want in the first place? Manipulating SQL can be very tricky, the syntax is full of nuances, so a general-purpose solution doesn't really exist.

Comment: @tadman: your point is good. But this string is used in two or three parts of the query out of which only one place I want to remove the above mentioned thing

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done using `substr()`, `replace()` and `indexOf()` methods.

For example,

```
var a = "and technology in('a', 'b') and subtechnology in('b', 'd')" 
var b = a.indexOf('technology')
var c = a.indexOf('and', b)
a = a.replace(a.substr(b, c-1), '')
```

Is there any more concise way to do this ?

Comment: `a.replace(/technology.*?(?=and)/, '')`?

Comment: @Amadan: your method is right. But it produces a string like `"and and subtechnology in('b', 'd')"`. I can manage that thing. Can you give me a good documentation of regex. A simple and not confusing one.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought one should stop *before* `"and"`. `a.replace(/technology\s+in\s*\([^)]*\)\s*and\s*/, '')` should work better anyway. Take a look at http://regular-expression.info

Answer (score 0):

What about string interpolation?

```
var values = "what ever you want";
var query = `and technology in(${values})`;
```

You have now a variable in your string and you can do what ever you want in your code with this variable.